# Unable to enable bearer authentication in Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, owin, azure-active-directory

I have an Web API project which is already implemented with the help of Class library and used PreapplicationStartMethod attribute to  set the routes for Web API. This Web API is added as Reference to MVC project in the same solution.

In MVC project, I have already enabled OpenIDConnectauthentication, now I need to enable bearer authentication for my Web API.

Can I use OWIN startup in order to enable windowsazurebearerauthentication in Web API as in my case Web API is developed with the help of Class Library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use OWIN startup in order to enable windowsazurebearerauthentication in Web API as in my case Web API is developed with the help of Class Library????

The PreapplicationStartMethod expanded support for application startup. It will not affect the OWIN comments and we can still use the bear authentication via Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory.

And this library can be used whatever how you developing with your web API. For example, you can develop the web API in a single method or use the library provided other library.

And regards to how to protect the web API with Azure AD, you can refer the link provide by Brent.